# script that finds a word from an array and adds tooltip on it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make a script that finds a list of words and replace each word with href link. for example

```js
function myFunction() {
        var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
        var res = str.replace("barbel", "<https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiFkyR35v2Y");
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Visit barbel</p>
    
<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```

Comment: Hello Bakar, you should write some codes and reask question when you stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `<a>` to display the link:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace("barbel", "<a href='https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XiFkyR35v2Y'>here</a>");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo">Visit barbel</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
```